# QDataWidgetMapper and multiple delegates

Tags: qt, pyqt, pyside

```
mapper = QtGui.QDataWidgetMapper()
mapper.setModel(my_table_model)
mapper.addMapping(widgetA, 0) #mapping widget to a column
mapper.addMapping(widgetB, 1) #mapping widget to a column
mapper.setItemDelegate(MyDelegateA(widgetA)) #Hmm. Where is the 'column' parameter?
mapper.setItemDelegate(MyDelegateB(widgetB)) #now itemDelegate is rewritten, MyDelegateB will be used
```

So... How do I set up mutiple delegates for a single `QDataWidgetMapper`? As far as I understand there is no `QDataWidgetMapper.setItemDelegateForColumn()` Or do I have to create some delegate factory, which will use appropriate delegates?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use one single delegate and handle the way behavior of the different widgets in the `setEditorData` and `setModelData` functions of the delegate. For an example (C++ but straight forward) check [this article from Qt Quarterly](http://doc.qt.io/archives/qq/qq21-datawidgetmapper.html).

Comment: Thanks, I've seen this article, but hoped for a more streamlined way to achieve the task. After all, I've allready got my delegates for QTableView with all the needed functionality. Oh well. If there is no anoter way...

Answer (score 3):

Ok, I got it. (At least, it works for me). So, the main idea is this class (a simplified  version), which keeps a list of real delegate instances and routes data to\from them:

```
class DelegateProxy(QtGui.QStyledItemDelegate):

    def __init__(self, delegates, parent=None):
        QtGui.QStyledItemDelegate.__init__(self, parent)
        self.delegates = delegates

    def setEditorData(self, editor, index):
        delegate = self.delegates[index.column()] 
        delegate.setEditorData(editor, index)

    def setModelData(self, editor, model, index):
        delegate = self.delegates[index.column()]
        delegate.setModelData(editor, model, index)
```

Fully working example is in the [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/wKE43U5H)

Answer (score 1):

I found this problem too, and it really sucks. I'm right now trying to subclass QtGui.QDataWidgetMapper in order to workaround this, the subclass having its own addMapping() with a delegate argument, a dict to store the delegate for each widget, and a matching meta-delegate that calls the appropiate delegate for each case.

The weirdest thing about this is the problem also existed in earlier versions of Qt 4 in QAbstractItemView (i.e tables and trees) and later was fixed adding the setItemDelegateForColumn() method, but QDataWidgetMapper didn't get the fix.

An alternative could be using more than a mapper, and connect them to keep them in sync if necessary, but it is a bit messy, specially if you need lots of different special delegates:

```
mainMapper = QtGui.QDataWidgetMapper()
mainMapper.setModel(my_table_model)

auxMapper1 = QtGui.QDataWidgetMapper()
auxMapper1.setModel(my_table_model)

# If you move the index in the main mapper, the auxiliary will follow
mainMapper.currentIndexChanged.connect(auxMapper1.setCurrentIndex)

mainMapper.addMapping(widgetA, 0) #mapping widget to a column
auxMapper1.addMapping(widgetB, 1) #mapping widget to a column

mainMapper.setItemDelegate(MyDelegateA(widgetA))
auxMapper1.setItemDelegate(MyDelegateB(widgetB))
```

Comment: Yes, I wholeheartedly agree with the 'really sucks' part.  Thanks for letting me know about you work. Do you have a blog or some other place I could track the progress?