# Read data from qabstractitemmodel via qdatawidgetmapper with BackgroundRole

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt5

I have the following question reagrding Qt (using PyQt 5):

I have modified one of the examples which I found for QDataWidgetMapper and QAbstractTableModel and added an additional if-clause for the role Qt.BackgroundRole to the data method.

The goal is to get different background colors depending on the content of my model (e.g. red background if the array element is equal to "error")

That works well for the qlistview2, but does not work for the qLineEdits, which are mapped to the model. I'm aware that this is not intended by the default QDataWidgetMapper (only one-by-one mapping of a section of the model to one property of a widget).

What would be the best practice to map additional properties/information to the line edits (to modify their style like background color, visibility, line edit enabled/not enabled)?

I need to do the computing for such properties inside the model (for a much more complex model) and do not want to subclass the QLineEdit (to implement there specific methods for changing the colors based on the QLineEdit text content).

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from  PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QWidget, QDataWidgetMapper,
                              QLineEdit, QApplication, QGridLayout, QListView)
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QAbstractTableModel, QModelIndex
from PyQt5.QtGui import QBrush


class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Window, self).__init__(parent)

        # Set up the widgets.
        self.nameEdit = QLineEdit()
        self.nameEdit2 = QLineEdit()

        # set up the layout
        layout = QGridLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.nameEdit, 0, 1, 1, 1)
        layout.addWidget(self.nameEdit2, 0, 2, 1, 1)
        self.setLayout(layout)

        self.mapper = None

    def setModel(self, model):
        # Set up the mapper.
        self.mapper = QDataWidgetMapper(self)
        self.mapper.setModel(model)
        self.mapper.addMapping(self.nameEdit, 0)
        self.mapper.addMapping(self.nameEdit2, 1)
        self.mapper.toFirst()


class MyModel(QAbstractTableModel):
    def __init__(self, data, parent=None):
        QAbstractTableModel.__init__(self, parent)
        self.lst = data

    def columnCount(self, parent=QModelIndex()):
        return len(self.lst[0])

    def rowCount(self, parent=QModelIndex()):
        return len(self.lst)

    def data(self, index, role=Qt.DisplayRole):
        row = index.row()
        col = index.column()

        if role == Qt.EditRole:
            return self.lst[row][col]
        elif role == Qt.DisplayRole:
            return self.lst[row][col]
        elif role == Qt.BackgroundRole:
            redBackground = QBrush(Qt.red)
            greenBackground = QBrush(Qt.green)
            if self.lst[row][col] == "error":
                return redBackground
            else:
                return greenBackground

    def flags(self, index):
        flags = super(MyModel, self).flags(index)

        if index.isValid():
            flags |= Qt.ItemIsEditable
            flags |= Qt.ItemIsDragEnabled
        else:
            flags = Qt.ItemIsDropEnabled

        return flags

    def setData(self, index, value, role=Qt.EditRole):

        if not index.isValid() or role != Qt.EditRole:
            return False

        self.lst[index.row()][index.column()] = value
        self.dataChanged.emit(index, index)
        return True


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    myModel = MyModel([['row 1 col1', 'error'],
                       ['error', 'row 2 col2'],
                       ['row 3 col1', 'row 3 col2'],
                       ['error', 'row 4 col2']])

    # myModel = MyModel()
    mywindow = Window()
    mywindow.setModel(myModel)

    qlistview2 = QListView()
    qlistview2.setModel(myModel)

    mywindow.show()
    qlistview2.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found the simple solution: I have to work with custom delegates to solve the problem.

```
class LineDelegate(QStyledItemDelegate):

    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        QStyledItemDelegate.__init__(self, parent)

    def createEditor(self, parent, option, index):
        pass

    def setEditorData(self, editor, index):
        editor.setText(index.model().data(index, Qt.EditRole))
        color = index.model().data(index, Qt.BackgroundColorRole)
        palette = QPalette()
        palette.setBrush(QPalette.Base,color)
        editor.setPalette(palette)
        editor.repaint()        

    def setModelData(self, editor, model, index):
        model.setData(index, editor.text(), Qt.EditRole)
```

As I need multiple delegates to handle both QLineEdits, [the question and answer given by AlexVhr](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10368966/2343241) helped a lot.

The complete modified source code is in the [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/ckvG85Ey).